# Wait for localhost in bash

Tags: bash, process

I was looking at how Create React App is tested. They are spawning a node.js child process with [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) and using this utility called [wait-for-localhost](https://github.com/sindresorhus/wait-for-localhost) to ensure that the server has been started correctly:

```js
const startProcess = execa('yarnpkg', ['start'], options);
await waitForLocalhost({ port });
```

How could I do something similar in Bash? I'd like to run the "start" script defined in my `package.json` file, wait for the server to be running on port 3,000 and immediately exit the process afterward.

Comment: ss -lnp | grep 3000 will show you whether there is a process listening on port 3000

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to start the process, test that it was run and started listening on port 3000, and then close it from within the same Bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
chk()
{
    ss -lnp | grep -q 3000
    if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]
    then
            echo "No process listening on port 3000 yet"
            sleep 1
            chk $1
    else
            echo "Killing process $1"
            kill -9 $1
    fi
}
npm start &
pid=$!
chk $pid
```

Spawn the react app to the background and not the process id as pid. Run the function chk and pass the pid. Within the function, use ss to output listening port and check for any process listening on port 3001. If nothing is listening, echo out a message and wait a second before running the function again. If grep returns a process running on port 3000, echo out a message and kill the process.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question: what is the role of the ampersand (&) placed after "npm start"? Wouldn't the script be equivalent if I rewrote that part like this: `pid=$(npm start)`?

Comment: & runs the npm process to the background and releases the terminal. Without the &, the npm process with run to the screen. $! then get the id of the background process.

Comment: Is it possible to use `nc` here instead of `ss`?

Comment: nc? You mean netstat?